# How to properly duplicate the same tab directory into another tab

Tags: cmder

How can I duplicate the directory of the specific tab in cmder, I tried right clicking and chose restart or duplicate > Duplicate Root but it won't duplicate instead it would go to my C:\users\My_pc drive

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track, you just needed to select `Split to Right` or `Split to Bottom` instead:

[image]

This will open a new tab to the right || bottom with the same directory as the duplicated tab.

Comment: It opens a new tab, but it is still in the home directory instead of the currnent directory of the previous tab